# Loading data from MySQL database to C# DGV

Tags: c#, mysql

I have MySQL database on QNAP and I created local copy using UwAmp. In MySQL Workbench it looks fine, but when I want to load data into my own DGV, it's not fine at all. Every cell have the same value and it's number 1. Also as I see there is some problem with encoding.

[Problem on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTUqZ.png)

Here's my connection string:

> Server=IP;Database=database;Uid=user;Pwd=password;convert zero datetime=True; default command timeout=500000; Connection Timeout = 500000

Comment: Can you please post the c# code where the DGV binds to the database?  If you are getting some data back, it is unlikely to be your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar problem, and it's almost always been the primary key not being set correctly in existing databases or the key not being set where you define the schema. Might be worth checking into.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found source of problem. MySQL Workbench (I have 6.3 and I don't know how it look in other versions) doesn't export views properly. It doesn't generate script like:

```
select o.id, o.number, c.name from order o join client c on o.client_id = c.client_id order by o.id
```

But something like this:

```
select '1' as id, '1' as number, '1' as name;
```

I have no idea why, but manual export fixed the issue.